# Django - filtering RelatedManager _set in template?

Tags: django, templates, filter

We have a Django DetailView where we're displaying an an object (`Site`), along with all of it's related objects (`Rooms`).

Now, in the template, we could simply iterate over the RelatedManager set:

```
{% for room in site.room_set.all %}
    do stuff
{% endfor %}
```

However, the problem for this is that this will pick up *all* related rooms to a site - however, we need to narrow this set down somewhat by another attribute (let's call it `year`) - and this attribute is stored in a Django session variable.

Currently, we're just using `Room.objects.filter(site=some_site, year='2009')` in the view code, and that's fine.

My question is more from curiosity - is there any way to use `_set` in the template, and still filter down or narrow the set?

Could you write a custom Model Manager to do this, so that `_set` will only ever return objects for the current year? Or is there some other way?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is more from curiosity - is there any way to use _set in
>   the template, and still filter down or narrow the set?

Not by default, since there's no way to pass arguments to the filter call.

- If it's functionality that needs to be repeated **variably**, often, and related to the template: build a custom template tag or filter (which can accept arguments).
- If it's functionality that's specific to a view, code it in the view.
- If it's functionality that's the same across multiple views, build the function in a dry place.

For #3, there are so many factors that determine where this code should go that there's no general solution. You could import a function into your views? Use a model manager? A model instance method? context processor? etc.

> Could you write a custom Model Manager to do this, so that _set will
>   only ever return objects for the current year? Or is there some other
>   way?

It looks like you can actually just by using a model manager for your reverse related model.

```
class RoomManager(models.Manager):
    def current_year(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(year=datetime.date.today().year)

for room in site.room_set.current_year():
   ...
```

Or just on the parent model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    ...
    def year_room_set(self):
        return self.room_set.filter(year=datetime.date.today().year)
```